# куча mmap в простейшем коде дампа stacktrace

Tags: c++, linux

здравствуйте, вот решил прогнать через strace бинарник хелловорлда:

```
#include<iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::cout<<"hello world";
}
```

с -О2 генерируется в это:

```
.LC0:
    .string "hello world\n"

main:
    subq    $8, %rsp
    movl    $.LC0, %esi
    movl    std::cout, %edi
    call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    addq    $8, %rsp
    ret

_GLOBAL__sub_I_main:
    subq    $8, %rsp
    movl    std::__ioinit, %edi
    call    std::ios_base::Init::Init()
    movl    $__dso_handle, %edx
    movl    std::__ioinit, %esi
    movl    std::ios_base::Init::~Init(), %edi
    addq    $8, %rsp
    jmp     __cxa_atexit
```

и вот теперь совершенно не ясно откуда такой выхлоп у strace:

```
execve("./exceptions", ["./exceptions"], [/* 39 vars */]) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x1d4d000
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7ff6f4a31000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=150385, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 150385, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7ff6f4a0c000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/5.4.0/libstdc++.so.6", 
O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\320\t\t\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=2051952, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4161184, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7ff6f4419000
mprotect(0x7ff6f45fe000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7ff6f47fd000, 69632, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1e4000) = 0x7ff6f47fd000
mmap(0x7ff6f480e000, 11936, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7ff6f480e000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libm.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\260V\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1062976, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3158248, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7ff6f4115000
mprotect(0x7ff6f4218000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7ff6f4417000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x102000) = 0x7ff6f4417000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/5.4.0/libgcc_s.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\220*\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=92312, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2188320, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7ff6f3efe000
mprotect(0x7ff6f3f14000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7ff6f4113000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x15000) = 0x7ff6f4113000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\340\3\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1656280, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3762456, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7ff6f3b67000
mprotect(0x7ff6f3cf4000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7ff6f3ef4000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x18d000) = 0x7ff6f3ef4000
mmap(0x7ff6f3efa000, 14616, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7ff6f3efa000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7ff6f4a0a000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7ff6f4a0b5c0) = 0
mprotect(0x7ff6f3ef4000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7ff6f4113000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7ff6f4417000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7ff6f4a08000
mprotect(0x7ff6f47fd000, 53248, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x600000, 4096, PROT_READ)     = 0
mprotect(0x7ff6f4a33000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7ff6f4a0c000, 150385)          = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x1d4d000
brk(0x1d7f000)                          = 0x1d7f000
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 0), ...}) = 0
write(1, "hello world", 11hello world)             = 11
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

поясните, пожалуйста, откуда такая куча mmap?

Comment: mmap в вашем случае переносит кусок модуля из файла в память.

Comment: т.е. типа вызов библиотечных функций?

Comment: ну т.е. dll во время работы подключается

Comment: Да, вам в трейс попали команды загрузки библиотек so ("dll").

Comment: @nick_n_a, хм, а почему дескриптор всегда 3 равен? разные файлы же

Comment: Потому что дескрипор в вашем случае - номер в таблице дескрипторов файлов даного процесса, и ваш номер 3 вы освобождаете командой close. Кстати в винде ситуация аналогичная, но дескрипторы нумеруются кратно 4 (winxp точно) и смешаны файловые с другими обьектами.

Comment: @nick_n_a, спасибо, вот только не пойму одного: mmap идет всегда после read из-за того, что read реализован с помощью mmap или в данном случае это не связанные вызовы функций?

Comment: Да, разные ф-ции. mmap не читает файл, а отображает. Read получает заголовок elf-файла по которому вычисляет сколько какх секций у библиотеки, а map - участок "секцию" библиотеки "мапит" в память. Возможно даже пересчитывает rellocation table. Видно даже что часть секций исполнимые, часть нет.

Comment: @nick_n_a по-моему, Вам пора уже комменты в виде ответа оформить :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

strace — это утилита, отслеживающая системные вызовы, которые представляют собой механизм трансляции, обеспечивающий интерфейс между процессом и операционной системой (ядром). Эти вызовы могут быть перехвачены и прочитаны. Это позволяет лучше понять, что процесс пытается сделать в заданное время. Перехватывая эти вызовы, мы можем добиться лучшего понимания поведения процессов, особенно если что-то идет не так. Функциональность операционной системы, позволяющая отслеживать системные вызовы, называется ptrace.

Про неё можно почитать [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace), [Ман](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) и [хабр](https://habrahabr.ru/post/215577/).

Теперь прокоментирую некоторые строчки дампа

`execve("./exceptions", ["./exceptions"], [/* 39 vars */]) = 0`

`brk(NULL)                               = 0x1d4d000`

`mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7ff6f4a31000`

`access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT`

`open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3` открытие файла, возврат дескриптора №3.
`fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=150385, ...}) = 0` посмотреть размер

`mmap(NULL, 150385, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7ff6f4a0c000`  Отобразить весь модуль кеша в гдеугодно памяти -> Размещён по адресу 7ff6f4a0c000
`close(3)` Закрыть дескриптор 3

`open("/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/5.4.0/libstdc++.so.6", 
O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3` открыть модуль, выдан снова уже свободный дескриптор №3.

`read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\320\t\t\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832` читаем заголовок файла (elf), дальше идёт расчёт секций

`fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=2051952, ...}) = 0` Получить размер файла

`mmap(NULL, 4161184, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7ff6f4419000` Помещаем одну из readonly секций  в память

`mprotect(0x7ff6f45fe000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0` резервируем секцию (? незнаю зачем, скорее всего для помещения туда данных c помощью mmap)

`mmap(0x7ff6f47fd000, 69632, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1e4000) = 0x7ff6f47fd000`
эту секцию на полный доступ

`mmap(0x7ff6f480e000, 11936, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7ff6f480e000` и эту секцию на полный доступ

`close(3)` закрыли файл

...

`brk(0x1d7f000)                          = 0x1d7f000`

`fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 0), ...}) = 0` это похоже подготовка консоли к работе.

`write(1, "hello world", 11hello world)` собственно ваш вывод в консоль

`exit_group(0)` ну и выход с программы.

О дескрипторах можно сказать что 1=STDOUT. 3=файл или свободный после close. 2 - не могу сказать что там. И последнее, mmap скорее всего делает поправку на таблицу размещения. Механизм линкования библиотек у линукса немного необычный, описывать его - отдельная статья.

Comment: ох, годно... спасибо, вот теперь попонятнее хоть чуток стало

Comment: добавлю еще вот ссыль https://xakep.ru/2011/01/13/54477/ где еще чуток объяснено для тех, кто не знает матчасти ( типа меня )

Comment: Дескриптор 2 это stderr